# Mocking filesystem for testing laravel artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel, testing

kinda stumped on how to test this. I'm working on building a command line tool that allows for the artisan make commands to be used outside of a laravel application. The idea being that this would allow artisan make commands to be used for package development anywhere on a dev system. I've got a working prototype, so I wanted to start adding in tests. However I'm a bit stumped on how to get the artisan command to execute inside of a mock filesystem (using mikey179/vfsStream). This is my current code:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStream;
use org\bovigo\vfs\vfsStreamWrapper;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan;

class ChannelCommandTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp(): void {
      parent::setUp();
      $structure = [
          'src' => [],
          'tests' => []
      ];
      $this->root = vfsStream::setup('newPackage', null, $structure);
      vfsStreamWrapper::register();
    }

    public function testChannelCommand(): void {
       Artisan::call('make:channel', ['name' => 'newChannel']);

       $this->assertFileExists('src/Channels/Broadcasting/newChannel.php');
    }
}
```